# Get a particular string using preg_match_all

Tags: php, string, preg-match-all

i want to find the string after "-" which is exactly in 3rd position, If it doesn't find the "-" it should get the whole string.
sample data are

```
TT-people // get people
1V-NEWTET // get NEWTET
ZZ-YESforTHE // get YESforTHE
Computer // get Computer
T-Book // get T-Book
```

I tried as

```
$result=preg_match_all("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]2-(\s\w*)/",$data,$networkID);
echo $networkID[0][1]
```

please rectify my error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and One thing I have forgot to mention that If the "-" is not found it should get the whole string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]2
```

The `2` here just matches the character “2”. Looks like you meant `{2}`.

To reflect your updated question, it should look like this:

```
$result = preg_match_all('/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-)?(\s\w*)/', $data, $networkID);
echo $networkID[0][1];
```

The `?` makes the group optional.

Comment: Thsnks for your reply. I am very sorry to say that I have miss out one point in my question. Now I have edited my question

Comment: @newcomer: That’s because of the `(\s\w*)`. Change it to `\w*`, probably (unless you needed the space for some reason? Why?) http://codepad.viper-7.com/Q72uWX

Comment: but when the character before the "-" is not equal to 2 character I got the wrong output. e.g. "T-NewokBi" give the "T" but I want to get "T-NewokBi"

Comment: @newcomer: Oh, just change the `{2}` (exactly 2) to `+` (at least one) then.

Answer (score 1):

if its a single line if text you can do:

```
if(substr($string, 2, 1) === "-"){
    echo substr($string, 3);
}else{
    echo $string;
}
```

Comment: Thsnks for your reply. I am very sorry to say that I have miss out one point in my question. Now I have edited my question